# label disappears if the countdown timer gets zero

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a Textblock (tbTime) which shows the countdown timer. when it gets zero, the Textblock (tbTime) shows still the zero values. But i wanna make this Textblock (tbTime) disappear, after the countdown timer reaches to zero.
Could anyone help me, please?

C# Code

```
public partial class InfoScreen : Window
    {

        DispatcherTimer timer;
                TimeSpan time;
        public InfoScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppearingNext();
            time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

            timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
            {
                tbTime.Text = time.ToString("ss");
                if (time == TimeSpan.Zero) timer.Stop();
                time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
            }, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
            if (tbTime.Text == "00") //My code doesn't work! 
            {
                tbTime.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }

        }
        private async void AppearingNext()
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            VisbilityPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }

        private void AgreementClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var registration = new Reset_Register();
            registration.Show();
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is put your code that hide the textblock inside the callback of the timer:

```
timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate {
    tbTime.Text = time.ToString("ss");
    if (tbTime.Text == "00") {
        tbTime.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    if (time == TimeSpan.Zero) timer.Stop();
    time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
}, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
```